# takepicture() gives Nullpointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera

I am building an camera app that uses the both camera front and rear but i get a null pointer error in this statement.

public void onClick(View view) {

```
  //camera.takePicture(shutter, raw, postview, jpeg)
  //camera.takePicture(null, null, new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
camera.takePicture(null, null,
    new PhotoHandler(MakePhotoActivity.this));
```

}

Please help me out as i dnt know wat the problem is over here.

Thanks in advance.

```
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    ... 11 more
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 23:06:12.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at com.example.cameraapp.MakePhotoActivity.onClick(MakePhotoActivity.java:41)
```

Comment: Post a log cat and a code.

Comment: we don't really have enough to go off of here. But from what you've posted it seems like `camera` is null when you are trying to call takePicture()

Comment: @FoamyGuy or PhotoHandler constructor referencing something that is null. Or getApplicationContext() is null (is called outsde of lifecycle)

Comment: i have added the logcat error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Change "getApplicationContext()" to "ActivityClassName.this"

Answer (score 0):

I am using a similer code as yours in my application and my app too used to throw null pointer exception on the line :

```
camera.takePicture(null, null,new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
```

I think this is caused due to the camera getting a null value.To avoid this exception I put a check on top of this line of code.So that the onClick function looks like :

```
public void onClick(View view) {
  if (camera != null) {
    Log.d("camera state","camera is NOT null");  
  }else{
    Log.d("camera state","camera is null");
    camera = android.hardware.Camera.open(cameraId);
  }
  camera.takePicture(null, null,new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
}
```

ps: my code was written for using just the front cam.Hope it helps !